# skip making temporary files and then write and read the result right away by using pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv

I read in an initial input csv file and revise it by:

- delete useless columns
- leave only the rows where the row name starts with '/a_'
- then create the table by csv file that collects the total connections between inputs and outputs that starts with letter '/a_'

But, as I don't need file like test1.txt and just want to make directly to test2.csv(final result) from the input file(csv_sample.txt)
How can I deal with this, by minimizing  the code?
I guess it would be much better if Pandas is used cus I'm not used to it..

and what If I apply this code to different csv input file( with same form, but different input numbers) without correcting the inner module at all?

Here's what I've done so far:

```
import csv
with open("./csv_sample.txt") as infile:    
    reader = csv.reader(infile)
    header = next(reader)
    data = list(reader)

useful_cols = set(['out_gate','in_gate','n_con'])
col_num, new_header = zip(*[(i,col) for i,col in enumerate(header) 
                          if col in useful_cols])

new_data = [[row[i] for i in col_num] for row in data]    
new_data = [row for row in new_data if row[0].startswith("/a_")]

with open("./test1.txt", "w") as outfile:
    writer = csv.writer(outfile)
    writer.writerow(new_header)
    writer.writerows(new_data)

import csv    
from collections import defaultdict    
d = defaultdict(lambda : defaultdict(int))

with open("./test1.txt") as in_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(in_file)
    next(csv_reader)
    for row in csv_reader:        
        if len(row) >= 3:
            x,y,count = row
        d[x][y] += int(count)

keys = sorted(d)        
new_data0 = [[d[x][y]for y in keys] for x in keys]    
new_data1 = [[new_data0[x][y] + new_data0[y][x] if x!=y else new_data0[x][y] for x in range(len(new_data0))] for y in range(len(new_data0[0]))]    
new_data2 = [[i]+j for i,j in zip(keys,new_data1)]    
keys.insert(0,' ')    
with open("test2.csv", "w") as outfile1:
    writer = csv.writer(outfile1)
    writer.writerow(keys)
    writer.writerows(new_data2)

[ csv_sample.txt ]

out_gate,uless_col,in_gate,n_con
p,x,x,1
p,x,/a_y,1
/a_a,x,z,1
/a_a,s,/a_a,3
/a_a,u,/a_b,1
/a_a,s,/a_b,3
/a_b,e,/a_a,2
/a_b,s,/a_b,2
/a_b,l,/a_c,4
/a_c,e,/a_a,5
/a_c,s,/a_b,5
/a_c,s,/a_b,3
/a_c,c,/a_a,4
/a_d,o,/a_c,2
/a_d,l,/a_c,3
/a_d,m,/a_b,2
p,y,/a_x,1
p,y,y,1
p,y,z,3

[ test1.txt ]

out_gate,in_gate,n_con    
/a_a,/a_b,1    
/a_a,/a_b,3    
/a_b,/a_a,2    
/a_b,/a_c,4    
/a_c,/a_a,5    
/a_c,/a_b,5    
/a_c,/a_b,3    
/a_c,/a_a,4    
/a_d,/a_c,2    
/a_d,/a_c,3    
/a_d,/a_b,2

    [test2.csv (shown as excel)]

    /a_a    /a_b    /a_c    /a_d

/a_a    3   6   9   0

/a_b    6   2   12  2

/a_c    9   12  0   5

/a_d    0   2   5   0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create `d` whilst you are reading in `csv_sample.txt`:

```
from collections import defaultdict
from operator import itemgetter
import csv

keep_cols = itemgetter(0, 2, 3)       # required column numbers
d = defaultdict(lambda : defaultdict(int))

with open('csv_sample.txt', newline='') as f_input:
    csv_input = csv.reader(f_input)
    next(csv_input) # skip header

    for row in csv_input:
        if row[0].startswith('/a_'):
            x, y, count = keep_cols(row)
            d[x][y] += int(count)

keys = sorted(d)        
new_data0 = [[d[x][y]for y in keys] for x in keys]    
new_data1 = [[new_data0[x][y] + new_data0[y][x] if x!=y else new_data0[x][y] for x in range(len(new_data0))] for y in range(len(new_data0[0]))]    
new_data2 = [[i]+j for i,j in zip(keys,new_data1)]    
keys.insert(0, ' ')    

with open('test2.csv', 'w', newline='') as f_output:
    csv_output = csv.writer(f_output)
    csv_output.writerow(keys)
    csv_output.writerows(new_data2)
```

As such, it is not necessary to write the text file.